# Как реализовать счетчик заказов в телеграм боте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Я только начала изучать Python и создание чат ботов, нужна помощь опытных.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как оформить код, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "Шаурма 1" срабатывал счётчик заказов и на кнопке возле названия появлялось (1), тоесть "Шаурма 1 (1)", и при каждом последующем нажатии кнопки количество увеличивалось на +1, а товар был добавлен в корзину.

Использую библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI и БД MySQL.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    area1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Шаурма 1', callback_data='1')
    area2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Шаурма 2', callback_data='2')
    area3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Шаурма 3', callback_data='3')
    key.add(area1, area2, area3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Воспользуйтесь кнопками ниже ⬇️, чтобы сделать свой заказ", reply_markup=key)

k=0

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c: True)
def inlin(c):
    global k
    k=k+1
    if c.data == '1':
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=c.id, text='Добавлено в корзину')
    if c.data == '2':
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=c.id, text='Добавлено в корзину')
    if c.data == '3':
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=c.id, text='Добавлено в корзину')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Накидал примерный алгоритм.

Использовал метод [edit_message_reply_markup](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/ce3c91b619074f062e89f8d16abaa6b569d970fd/telebot/__init__.py#L1205), чтобы поменять только кнопки под сообщением.

Попробуйте:

```
import threading

...

# Для синхронизации потоков
lock = threading.Lock()

# Кэш подготавливаемых заказов. По хорошему, нужно сделать еще один ключ -- chat_id и хранить в нем состояние: текст, счетчик и т.п.
ORDER_CACHE = {
    "1": 0,
    "2": 0,
    "3": 0,
}
def get_order_text_counter(data: str) -> str:
    return f' ({ORDER_CACHE[c.data]})' if ORDER_CACHE[c.data] else ''


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c: True)
def inlin(c):
    if c.data not in ORDER_CACHE:
        return

    # Только один поток в один момент может обращаться к коду
    with lock:
        # Обновление счетчика заказа
        ORDER_CACHE[c.data] += 1

    # Подготовка встроенных кнопок с обновленным текстом
    key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    area1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Шаурма 1' + get_order_text_counter("1"), callback_data='1')
    area2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Шаурма 2' + get_order_text_counter("2"), callback_data='2')
    area3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Шаурма 3' + get_order_text_counter("3"), callback_data='3')
    key.add(area1, area2, area3)

    # Меняем кнопки под сообщением
    bot.edit_message_reply_markup(c.message.chat_id, c.message.message_id, reply_markup=key)

    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=c.id, text='Добавлено в корзину')
```

---

**UPD.**

А так я бы описал структуру подготовленных заказов. Но чтобы эти заказы не было общими для всех клиентов, нужно создавать отдельные для отдельных чатов. Получится словарь, у которого ключом будет `chat_id`, а значением словарь вида `ORDER_CACHE`

Пример:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import threading

...

# Для синхронизации потоков
lock = threading.Lock()


@dataclass
class Order:
    title: str
    number: int = 0

    def get_total_title(self) -> str:
        return self.title + f' ({self.number})' if self.number else ''

ORDER_CACHE = {
    "1": Order('Шаурма 1'),
    "2": Order('Шаурма 2'),
    "3": Order('Шаурма 3'),
}
def get_inline_keyboard_markup() -> types.InlineKeyboardMarkup:
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

    for data, order in ORDER_CACHE.items():
        button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=order.get_total_title(), callback_data=data)
        markup.add(button)

    return markup


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    markup = get_inline_keyboard_markup()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Воспользуйтесь кнопками ниже ⬇️, чтобы сделать свой заказ", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c: True)
def inlin(c):
    # Если заказ с указанной data не поддерживается
    if c.data not in ORDER_CACHE:
        return

    # Обновление счетчика заказа
    if lock:
        ORDER_CACHE[c.data] += 1

    # Подготовка встроенных кнопок с обновленным текстом
    markup = get_inline_keyboard_markup()

    # Меняем кнопки под сообщением
    bot.edit_message_reply_markup(c.message.chat_id, c.message.message_id, reply_markup=markup)

    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=c.id, text='Добавлено в корзину')
```

---

**PS.**

Накидал пару примеров на `python-telegram-bot`:

1. [Тут используется то](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/3327adaf480a96947e31df589a8d4b9f55224952/telegram_bot_examples/counter_in__InlineKeyboardButton__telegram_context.py#L64), что телеграм помнит состояние кнопок, поэтому мы получаем значения этих кнопок, меняем в них текст и отправляем подправленную клавиатуру
2. [А тут используется кэш в словаре](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/3327adaf480a96947e31df589a8d4b9f55224952/telegram_bot_examples/counter_in__InlineKeyboardButton__cache_dict.py#L97) и восстановление значения словаря от состояний кнопок, полученных от телеграмма, если в словаре их уже нет -- например если был перезапуск бота

Насчет `threading.Lock`... он используется для того, что убрать эффект гонки потоков ([наглядный пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/4cd07ab1cc974c1d538d5c08834ecdcd8f5a4b40/multithreading__threading__examples/race_condition.py#L47)). Гонка может возникнуть, когда несколько потоков одновременно обращаются к какой-то области.

Например, при увеличении числа на 1:

- Нужно сначала взять значение из переменной
- После к этому значению прибавить 1
- И новое значение положить в переменную

В случаи нескольких потоков может случиться так, что одновременно потоки возьмут значение из переменной, прибавят и положат, при этом какие-то потоки успеют раньше других это сделать, какие-то позже. Чтобы такой ситуации избежать, нужен `lock` (а так, для этой темы нужно почитать про мьютексы и семафоры)

Comment: Спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли!

Comment: @Julieta, пожалуйста :)